# How to get Views Total number of records in Page.tpl.php file. (Before Views rendered)

Tags: blocks, views

See [this image](http://prntscr.com/7idx70) for more understanding.

I want to fetch Views total number of records in page.tpl.php before views.tpl called. Is it possible to fetch that row total  before views rendered?
I am also using contextual filter for this view. Views have page type display.

I have also used module [views_record_count](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_record_count). but this will print total number of records on Views header or footer. (Not outside of views)

Comment: I don't think it's possible before the view is rendered. You can always use css to move the count up from your view's header, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for reply I have also tried to replicate total rows count div from views header [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427094/how-can-i-duplicate-a-div-onclick-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code to print the count.

```
<?php

$view = views_get_view( 'test' );
$view->set_display('block');
$view->set_arguments( array( 1, 2, 3 ) );
$view->execute();
$count = count( $view->result );
print $count;

?>
```